# Unable to share data using Shared App Groups for Today Extension

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfilemanager, ios8-today-widget

I am trying to create a today extension that displays data from the parent app by using a shared app group container, and then adding the persistent store to a context.

- Add Today Extension Target
- Turn on app groups for parent app and extension and select same group
- Add Today Extension as Target Membership for Data model and entities
- Add Persistent store to context
- Fetch Objects

I get no errors but the extension does not seem to be fetching any results. Does anybody have any suggestions where I may be going wrong ?

Heres what I am doing in the extension `TodayViewController`

```
class TodayViewController: UIViewController, NCWidgetProviding {

var context: NSManagedObjectContext!

@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
var objectsArray = [Objects]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    var containerPath = fileManager.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.com.Company.AppName")

    containerPath = containerPath?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("AppName", withExtension: "momd")
    let model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL!)
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model!)
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: containerPath, options: nil)
    } catch {
     print("yellow")
    }

    context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator


    let moc = context
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Objects")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]


    do {
        try
            self.objectsArray = moc.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Objects]
            print ("objects count \(objectsArray.count)")
    } catch {
        // failure
        print("Fetch failed")
    }

    self.table.reloadData()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    //return sectionsArray.count

    return 1
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.objectsArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell!

   cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
   cell.textLabel!.text = self.objectsArray[indexPath.row].title

   return cell

}

func widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((NCUpdateResult) -> Void)) {
    // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

    // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResult.Failed
    // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResult.NoData
    // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResult.NewData

    completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.NewData)
}

}
```

Comment: It was easy for me to share all kinds of data between my main app and a today extension with app groups and NSUserDefaults. This takes maybe 15 mins to set up! See step 5 and beyond here: http://www.glimsoft.com/06/28/ios-8-today-extension-tutorial/

Answer (score 3):

In Apple's *App Extension Programming Guide* --**Sharing Data with Your Containing App**

> Even though an app extension bundle is nested within its containing app’s bundle, the running app extension and containing app have no direct access to each other’s **containers**.

So they wouldn't be able to share data directly,even if you

> Add Today Extension as Target Membership for Data model and entities

Instead,they communicated with each other by shared container(App groups) indirectly,which you had already setup in step 2.

[image]

So the solution is :

1. In your Contraning App,create the sql data model in your shared container ,insert data in this database.Adjust your code in todayExtension ,and fetch data.
2. Or Using *NSUserDefaults*  to share data instead.

like this:

```
// Create and share access to an NSUserDefaults object
NSUserDefaults *mySharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName: @"com.example.domain.MyShareExtension"];

// Use the shared user defaults object to update the user's account
[mySharedDefaults setObject:theAccountName forKey:@"lastAccountName"];
```